# How do i create button on the UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

How to create a UIPopoverController with buttons like the following figure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use UISagmentcontrol to set this type of button in your UIPopoverController.You create UISagmentcontrol object and add this your UIPopoverController.